# Springfox Swagger and Spring Data Rest Problems

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, swagger-2.0, springfox

I've been trying to configure a project that uses spring-data-rest to use swagger springfox, following the documentations available [here (spring-data-rest)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) and [here (springfox)](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/).

It happens that the swagger documentation generated seems wrong, at a first glance.
What I mean with wrong is that swagger documentation doesn't show operations of entities, but of its attributes.

I created an exampĺe project to show what I mean. You can find it [here](https://github.com/luizgustavoss/swagger-spring-data-rest).

In this project I have two simple entities.

Module.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Module {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long uuid;

    @NotNull(message = "A name is necessary")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent", nullable = true)
    private Module parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "application", nullable = true)
    private Application application;

}
```

Application.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ApiModel(value = "Applications", description = "Applications")
public class Application {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long uuid;

    @NotNull(message = "A name is necessary")
    private String name;

}
```

Repositories are pretty simple too.

ApplicationRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
@Api(tags={"Application Repository"})
public interface ApplicationRepository extends CrudRepository<Application, String> {

}
```

ModuleRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
@Api(tags={"Module Repository"})
public interface ModuleRepository extends CrudRepository<Module, String> {

}
```

I expected to find in swagger documentation for both entities, but I just get documentation related to Module attributes, and no documentation related to Application.

Documentation Generated:

[image: Documentation Generated]

Details of Module documentation:

[image: Details of Module documentation]

Endpoint generated by Spring Data Rest:

[image: Endpoint generated by Spring Data Rest]

What is wrong here? I expected to have documentations for both Application 
 (/applications)and Module (/modules), as listed by the generated endpoints, but swagger doesn't recognize it, and assumes just the relations, ignoring entities with no relations:

[image]